# Responsive position of row elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small problem in the responsive alignment of my row elements

[image]

I have 3 panel (with class : col-lg-6 col-md-6) in one row and I want to align the last panel with the heigh of the first.

I tried to add a :  but nothing change...

Someone know how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

...You can do what you are after by using this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        top panel
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        bottom panel
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  right panel
</div>
```

edit: the -lg-X isn't needed if it's the same number as the one in the lower breakpoint.